# Different output for same Ruby Code?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.3

I have written a code to convert morse code into characters. The thing is when I run this code on terminal, and through IRB, I get output as expected, but when I run  the same code on online IDE, I get different output.

Code:

```
$morse_dict = {
  "a" => ".-",
  "b" => "-...",
  "c" => "-.-.",
  "d" => "-..",
  "e" => ".",
  "f" => "..-.",
  "g" => "--.",
  "h" => "....",
  "i" => "..",
  "j" => ".---",
  "k" => "-.-",
  "l" => ".-..",
  "m" => "--",
  "n" => "-.",
  "o" => "---",
  "p" => ".--.",
  "q" => "--.-",
  "r" => ".-.",
  "s" => "...",
  "t" => "-",
  "u" => "..-",
  "v" => "...-",
  "w" => ".--",
  "x" => "-..-",
  "y" => "-.--",
  "z" => "--..",
  " " => " ",
  "1" => ".----",
  "2" => "..---",
  "3" => "...--",
  "4" => "....-",
  "5" => ".....",
  "6" => "-....",
  "7" => "--...",
  "8" => "---..",
  "9" => "----.",
  "0" => "-----"
}

def decodeMorse(morseCode)
  words = morseCode.split('       ')
  i=0
  sentence = []
  while i < words.length
    word = words[i].split(' ')
    j = 0 
    while j < word.length
      sentence.push($morse_dict.key(word[j]))
      if word.length - j == 1
        sentence.push(' ')  
      end
    j += 1
  end
  i += 1
  end
  sentence = sentence.join().upcase
  return sentence  
end

sentence= decodeMorse('.... . -.--       .--- ..- -.. .')
puts sentence
```

Output I get in console and IRB: `HEY JUDE`
Output I get in online editors: `HEYJUDE`

I dont understand why the in-space(HEY(space)JUDE) gets deleted and its appended at end in online editors(HEYJUDE(space)).

To check my code further, I put some checks as  `Iteration #{j}`  in inner while loop, and I got very weird behavior. What I got in output was:

```
Iteration 1
Iteration 2
Iteration 3
Iteration 4
Iteration 5
Iteration 6
Iteration 7
```

instead of

```
Iteration 1
Iteration 2
Iteration 3

Iteration 1
Iteration 2
Iteration 3
Iteration 4
```

Why this behavior ?
I've tried my best to follow ruby syntax style, but I'm new!

Comment: Works for me. I'd guess that copying your code to the online IDE changes whitespace somewhere. Can you save your code in the online IDE and show us a link that reproduces the problem, or better yet copy your code to the online IDE and back and reproduce the problem on your machine?

Answer (score -2):

This code could be a lot simpler... Try something like this (I didn't bother pasting the `morse_dict` global) (p.s. try to avoid using global vars like this):

```
def decode_morse(morse_code)
  morse_dict = { ... } # placeholder, use your actual map here
  out = []
  morse_code.split('       ').each do |w|
    w.split(' ').each do |l|
      out.push morse_dict.invert[l] # actual letter
    end
    out.push ' ' # after each word
  end
  out.join.strip # final output
end
```

Comment: Its very neat, however I have to understand how it works.
 But it does not answer my question. I want to know the reason for the behavior that I was getting ?